# Can't save the right image url on Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I am getting data by user, saving it in a map and adding this item to a list. When user has added all items in the list, it press the floating action button to add this list to an existing list on the firestore.
All data is being saved successfully except the imageUrl. **First item in the list has null imageUrl at firestore however the second item is assigned the imageUrl of first Item. And the sequence goes on...** I don't know what am I missing! I have subtracted most of code to be specific. I think the problem is being caused by the variable **itemImageUrl** that is being overridden. Help!

This is the code:

```
class RetrieveShop extends StatefulWidget {
  String nameShop;String docId;


  RetrieveShop(this.nameShop,this.docId);

  @override
  _RetrieveShopState createState() => _RetrieveShopState();
}

class _RetrieveShopState extends State<RetrieveShop> {
  var result;

  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLoadingNow = false;
  var _price = TextEditingController();
  var _itemName = TextEditingController();

/*  var _id = TextEditingController();
  var _category = TextEditingController();*/
  var _desc = TextEditingController();
  File _image;
  File _image2;
  String itemImageUrl;

  bool _showDg = false;
  bool condition = true;
  bool isPopular = false;
  bool savingAllDataToFirestore = false;
  List itemo=[];

  Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker()
        .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 80);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }

  Future getImageFromCamera() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }

  Future uploadItemOfShop(BuildContext context) async {
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child(
        "${this.widget.nameShop}'s ${_itemName.text} Price ${_price.text}" +
            DateTime.now().toString());
    if (_image.toString() == '') {
      Flushbar(
        title: "Menu Item Image is empty",
        message: "Please Add some Image first",
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        boxShadows: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.red[800],
            offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
            blurRadius: 3.0,
          )
        ],
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      )
        ..show(context);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoadingNow=true;
      });
      debugPrint('wah');
      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image);
      uploadTask.then((res) async {
        itemImageUrl = await res.ref.getDownloadURL();
      }).then((value){
        setState(() {
          isLoadingNow=false;
        });
        debugPrint("Nullifing the Image object");
        _image=_image2; //Trying to null the file object after it is used so thinking that might 
                      //the problem is being caused here
      });

    }
  }


  Widget listTile(BuildContext context,String doc) {
    return !isLoadingNow?SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Wrap(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Enter details of Item",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black87),
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  height: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .height / 2.5,
                  child: (_image != null)
                      ? Image.file(
                    _image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                      : Image.network(
                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502164980785-f8aa41d53611?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  color: Colors.white38,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add_a_photo,
                          size: 30.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getImageFromCamera();
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.create_new_folder_rounded,
                          size: 30.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getImageFromGallery();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        subtitle: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _itemName,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Item name',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintText: "Zinger Burger etc"),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _price,
              autofocus: false,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Price',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintText: "70 etc"),
            ),

            SwitchListTile(
              title: condition ? Text("Fresh") : Text("Used"),
              value: condition,
              onChanged: _onConditionChanged,
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              title: isPopular ? Text("Popular") : Text("Not Popular"),
              value: isPopular,
              onChanged: _onPopularityChanged,
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: false,
              maxLength: 150,
              controller: _desc,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Description',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.description),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintText:
                  "This item contains cheez and paneer with delicious mayonees etc.."),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Save",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () {

                      if(_image !=null){
                        int price=int.parse(_price.text);
                        String itemName=_itemName.text;
                        String itemDesc=_desc.text;
                        String categoryO=this.categoryToSave;
                        String imageUrl=this.itemImageUrl;
                    
                        uploadItemOfShop(context).then((value){
                          String idO=getRandomString(3);
                          var item = {
                            'itemName': itemName,
                            'itemPrice': price,
                            'itemDesc': itemDesc,
                            'category': categoryO,
                            'condition': condition,
                            'imageUrl': imageUrl,
                            'isPopular': this.isPopular,
                            'id': idO,
                          };

                          setState(() {
                            itemo.add(item);
                          });


                        });
                        setState(() {
                          _showDg = false;
                        });
                        _price.clear();
                        _desc.clear();
                        _itemName.clear();
                       /* imageUrl='';
                        itemImageUrl='';*/


                      }else{
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please select some image first');
                      }


                    }
                    ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        selectedTileColor: Colors.red.shade300,
      ),
    ):Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: Center(
        child:CircularProgressIndicator()
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myList(String nameOfButton2, {BuildContext buildContext}) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shops').where(
              'name', isEqualTo: this.widget.nameShop).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              DocumentSnapshot list=snapshot.data.docs.single;
              return isLoadingNow
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.data()['menu'].length,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context,int index){
                  return Card(
                    shadowColor: Colors.red,
                    //color: Colors.black,
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    //borderOnForeground: true,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 10, right: 10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading:  CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        //height: 100,
                        placeholderFadeInDuration:
                        Duration(seconds: 2),
                        fadeOutDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        imageUrl: list
                            .data()['menu'][index]['imageUrl'],
                        progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url,
                            downloadProgress) =>
                            Center(
                                child:
                                CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  value: downloadProgress.progress,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                )),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                            Icon(Icons.error),
                      ),
                      title:Text('Name: ${list.data()['menu'][index]['itemName']}'),

                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children:[
                          Text(
                            "Price: ${list.data()['menu'][index]['itemPrice']} Rs",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Description: ${list.data()['menu'][index]['itemDesc']}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          list.data()['menu'][index]['condition']
                              ? Text("Condition: Fresh")
                              : Text("Condition: Used"),
                        ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Text('Please try again');
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );

          },
        ),

      ]
      ,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("${this.widget.nameShop}"),
          centerTitle: false,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_comment),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showDg = !_showDg;
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _showDg ? listTile(context,this.widget.docId) : Text(""),
                myList(this.widget.nameShop),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text("Items ${itemo.length.toString()}"),
        onPressed: (){
          if(itemo.length==0){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please add some items first');
          }else{
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shops').doc(this.widget.docId).update({
              "menu": FieldValue.arrayUnion(itemo),
            });
            setState(() {
              itemo=[];
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was just missing **await** before the object of uploadtask.